# How to build Android project with ant and annotation processing

Tags: android, ant, annotations, android-annotations

I'm currently working on an Android project using both Android annotation and Storm-gen.
I have no problem build my project with Eclipse but when it come to Ant I'm lost.

Here my configuration when the project only have storm-gen

```
java.compilerargs=-processorpath libs/annotations/storm-apt-0.97.jar -processor com.turbomanage.storm.apt.MainProcessor -s .apt_generated
```

Any idea how to add a second annotation processor ?

Answer (score 1):

I just added those configurations to an ant.properties file and use build file that was generated by the instructions from [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)
something like this

android update project --name MyApp --target 2 --path ./MyAppProject

Answer (score 0):

The ant documentation [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) says that it's a space delimited list.

You ought to be able to append further '-processorpath path' blocks.